# I have the ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined error

Tags: javascript, jquery, struts-1, absolute-path

In Struts i have to go to action, before it renders a page for first time.It cannot find my jQuery files by specifying Absolute path(`"/js/jquery.js"`).

Comment: You already know the answer then! `It cannot find my jQuery files by specifying Absolute path`

Comment: i did specified with relative path js/jquery.js it does work. but other .js files are not resolved.

Comment: Use developer out whether jQuery (a) is not loaded **yet** or (b) is failing to load at all. Check your Network panel to see if /js/jquery.js is red (failure). After your page load, enter a jQuery command in your console. Edit your question with what you learn.